# How do I integrate amazon results in my classifieds website?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have a classifieds website (with geoclassifieds basic) and would like to integrate amazon results into the search results. What's a simple  way to to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to apply for an account at http://aws.amazon.com and get an API key.  Authenticating to the API is somewhat involved, so you might want to have a look at something like http://gulati.info/2009/08/amazon-php-api/.  Documentation for the Amazon Product Advertising API can be found at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/.